# Problem after generating released apk file in flutter

Tags: flutter, apk

I generated the released apk file in flutter using android studio. But after generating the file it was installed in real time mobile but not working. It shows host name error in the console. How to resolve this error?

Comment: Try with release apk or build apk.

Comment: i was tried both debug and release apk file.it was installed and after that i am trying to login it shows the error i.e host name error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to your Manifest.xml file  `android/app/src/main`, because flutter do this only for development version 
under

Comment: Yes i was added the internet permission also but it shows same erroe